# express 4.x router cannot get / 404 all routes including test

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed all modules using the latest versions and seen many issues similar, but not the same thing. This must be in these 3 small files. If you need more information, please comment.

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var product = require('./routes/product'); // Imports routes for the products
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/products', product);


var port = 3002;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port numbner ' + port);
});
```

routes/product.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Require the controllers WHICH WE DID NOT CREATE YET!!
var product_controller = require('../controllers/product');

router.all('*', function(req,res){ res.send(200, req.originalUrl) })
// a simple test url to check that all of our files are communicating correctly.
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);


module.exports = router;
```

controller:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

//Simple version, without validation or sanitation
exports.test = function (req, res) {
    res.send('Greetings from the Test controller!');
};
```

The server is up and running, but when I GET http://localhost:3002/test

Cannot GET /test

Comment: Step 1: _drastically siimplify your code to see if it's just you_ by throwing away _everything_ that isn't just a simple `app.get('/', (req,res) => { res.html('k this works'); })` and then work your way back up until things break again. Congrats: you just found the problem and either it turns out it's easily fixed with some web searching, or you now have far better information to post to SO for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing `http://localhost:3002/products/test`.

```js
// You're mounting the product router onto the base route of /products.
// Any route defined in the product router must be prefixed with the left-hand value.
app.use('/products', product);
```